# How to specify two-way bindable property in HTML-only custom element (Aurelia)

Tags: aurelia

I have created an HTML-only custom element to represent an input and all the DOM structure that does with it.

I have set up bindable properties on the template to supply values into the element.  However, I don't see a way to specify that a bindable should be two-way.

**the element:**

```
<template bindable="label,name,placeholder,value">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for.bind="name">${label}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6">
            <input class="form-control" id.bind="name" placeholder.bind="placeholder" value.bind="value" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I know I can specify two-way binding each time the element is used (e.g.  `<my-element value.bind="firstName & twoWay"></my-element>`, but I want to set the default without having to create and maintain a separate class (i.e. I like html-only element for this case).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible in a simple way. I mean, you could figure out how to override the default behaviour somehow ([[source]](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/blob/master/src/html-resource-plugin.js), [[source]](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/blob/master/src/dynamic-element.js)), but it's likely that you would end up with several more classes to maintain.

[Documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-html-behaviors-introduction/7) is clear about that:

> You can even have bindable properties on your HTML Only Custom Element. These properties default to one-way databinding, but you can't change the default, though you are still free to explicitly set the binding direction when you bind to the Custom Element.

In my opinion, using `.two-way` explicit binding is your simplest option here.

`<my-element value.two-way="firstName"></my-element>`